# BigQuery Python API cannot query the table created using GoogleSheet

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I have a table (gs_table) created using GoogleSheet as a datasource.

When using python API, I get the error whenever the gs_table is in the query.
For e.g.:

`SELECT r.id AS retailer_id, p.id AS product_id
FROM [dataset.gs_table] r 
JOIN [dataset.csv_imported_table] p
ON r.id = p.retailer_id`

RuntimeError: {u'reason': u'internalError', u'message': u'An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed.'}

This happens to all table if the source is GoogleSheet.

Executing the same query in BigQuery UI is perfectly fine.

Is this a limitation of the API or a bug?

Comment: error happened with only gs_table, or all tables? Most time internal error means something wrong happened in server side, and it should be bug, I guess it may be better to ask google team

Comment: only with gs_table. Other queries not related to googlesheet table runs fine.

Comment: could you show gs_table table description? That seems to be related with special table as you said